# vim scrolls wrong window

Tags: vim, scroll, split

I am using vim 7.4 under Ubuntu Linux.
When I split window by using ":sp hello.c", 
if I click the upper window, then the mouse wheel scrolls the upper window.
But if I click the lower window, then depending on which part of the lower window I click, it scrolls either the upper window or the lower window.
Specifically, if I click inside the upper half of the lower window, it scrolls the upper window; if I click inside the lower half of the lower window, it scrolls the lower window.
How can I make it work correctly?
Thanks.

Comment: What are your `vimrc` settings?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my setting:

```
  ambiwidth=double    helplang=ko       nomodeline            ruler               syntax=php          ttymouse=xterm2
  filetype=php        history=50          mouse=a             scroll=25           ttyfast
  backspace=indent,eol,start
  fileencoding=utf-8
  fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,default,latin1
  printoptions=paper:a4
  runtimepath=~/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim74,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vi
m/addons/after,~/.vim/after
  suffixes=.bak,~,.swp,.o,.info,.aux,.log,.dvi,.bbl,.blg,.brf,.cb,.ind,.idx,.ilg,.inx,.out,.toc
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around this problem, by adding the following lines to my .vimrc file:

```
noremap <ScrollWheelUp>     4<C-Y>
noremap <ScrollWheelDown>   4<C-E>
noremap <S-ScrollWheelUp>   <C-B>
noremap <S-ScrollWheelDown> <C-F>
```

from the following document:
https://superuser.com/questions/351972/how-can-i-change-the-scroll-wheel-behavior-in-vim-so-that-it-scrolls-instead-of